# Getting Keyboard events for iOS UIView which contains a textField

Tags: c#, ios

I find it is pretty straightforward to add a gesture recogniser to a textField i.e. textField.EditingDidBegin // textField.EditingDidEnd etc.

However, I have created a new view controller extending a UIView which contains a textField which I use in quite a few places.

I need to create a new gesture recognizer to change the behaviour of my EditingDidBegin // EditingDidEnd on the UITextField contained in my class. I am struggling to this because I am not sure how to override the gesture recognizer already attached to the text field as well as not being able to access that TextField from another class (obviously)

Comment: Which programming language are you using i.e, Swift or Objective-C? and also your question is not so clear.

Comment: I'm using c#. Sorry about that @JayachandraA I basically had a custom view which inherited from a UIView and in there I had a textField which was no accessible when creating a new instance of my custom view. I was trying to listen to events on the textField on a new instance of my custom view

Comment: check my answer below.

Comment: Thanks I got it to work in a similar way :) @JayachandraA

Comment: that's great, then accept my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a custom view like `MyView: UIView` and using it in another `ViewController`.

Declare protocol to handle TextField events in another `ViewController` or `View` from `MyView`.

```
protocol MyViewDelegate {

    func fieldBeginEditin(_ aTextField: UITextField)

    func fieldEndEditin(_ aTextField: UITextField)
}
```

Your custom view

```
class MyView: UIView, UITextFieldDelegate {

    //assume you have textfield object here
    var _textField: UITextField!
    var delegate: MyViewDelegate?

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        setupInterface()
    }

    func setupInterface() {
        if _textField == nil {
            _textField = UITextField(frame: .zero)
            _textField.delegate = self
        }
    }

    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        delegate?.fieldEndEditin(textField)
    }

    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        delegate?.fieldEndEditin(textField)
    }
}
```

Handling Textfield events from where you have added your custom view

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, MyViewDelegate{

        var myView = MyView(frame: .zero)

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            myView.delegate = self
        }

        func fieldEndEditin(_ aTextField: UITextField) {
            print(#function)
        }

        func fieldBeginEditin(_ aTextField: UITextField) {
            print(#function)
        }
    }
```

**NOTE:**
apply the same logic with C# code